# Small issue initializing a variable and/or updating the value throughout the code

Tags: java

I had a functional version earlier that used less unique variables and just more instances of the first variable, but after adding in two more variables whose values are related to the first one, my code comes up with an error showing that I need to initialize my variable "numbList".

Ideally I'd like to simply update the value of "numbList" after each new line, which will then update the values of "numbSquare" and "numbCube". So far I haven't had much luck.

```
public class Assignment2BPart2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numbList;
        int numbSquare;
        int numbCube;

        numbSquare = numbList * numbList;
        numbCube = numbSquare * numbList;

        System.out.println("The following is a table of values, showing numbers 0 - 10 and their squares and cubes.");
        System.out.printf("%s%s%s%n", "Number   ", "Square  ", "Cube");
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 0, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 1, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 2, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 3, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 4, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 5, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 6, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 7, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 8, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 9, numbSquare, numbCube);
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 10, numbSquare, numbCube);       
    }
}
```

The expected results would be a 3 column table with header reading

> Number  Square  Cube

With the rest of column 1 being values 0-10, column 2 being the squares of those numbers, and column 3 being the cubes of the numbers.

So far I'm not able to run the code in this iteration.

Comment: local variables need to be initialized before using them

Comment: "numbList = 0" is this not initializing the variable?

Comment: that is after this statement `numbSquare = numbList*numbList;
        numbCube = numbSquare*numbList;`

Comment: Try to focus on Basic Concepts like For Loop, While Loop and DO-While.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong, you have to calculate the square and cube after updating the `numbList`, so you have to do this by using any of the loops or recursion, but i will prefer having two methods returns int value one for calculating square and other for cube

```
public class NewMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numbList = 0;


    System.out.println("The following is a table of values, showing numbers 0 - 10 and their squares and cubes.");

    System.out.printf("%s%s%s%n", "Number   ", "Square  ", "Cube");

    //
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 0, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 1, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 2, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 3, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 4, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 5, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 6, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 7, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 8, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 9, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", numbList = 10, squareOfNumber(numbList), cubeOfNumber(numbList));
}

public static int squareOfNumber(int num) {
    return num*num;
}
public static int cubeOfNumber(int num) {
    return num*num*num;
  }
}
```

**for loop** you can apply the same logic above

```
for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", i, i*i, i*i*i);
    }
```

You can also use `Math.pow()`

```
nt intResult = (int) Math.pow(2, 3);
```

> The method raises 2 to the power of 3 and returns the result

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for is how to make the code and variables reusable. One way to do this is with functions, though you may not be up to learning about this yet. You would then use a for loop to input then numbers 1 to 10 in to your function to obtain the desired output.

```
 public static int NumberSquared(int number)
 {
    return number*number;
 }

 public static int NumberCubed(int number)
 {
    return number*number*number;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

    for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " Square: " + NumberSquared(i) + " Cube: " + NumberCubed(i));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve something repetitive like this is to use a [`for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
System.out.println("The following is a table of values, showing numbers 0 - 10 and their squares and cubes.");
System.out.printf("%s%s%s%n", "Number   ", "Square  ", "Cube");

for (int num = 0; num <= 10; num++) {
    System.out.printf("%d \t %d \t %d%n", num, num * num, num * num * num);
}
```

Comment: These are awesome responses, everyone. Thank you a ton.

I've gone back to the drawing board, unfortunately we haven't learned loops or any sort of recursion yet. I know it's probably very soon, but there's been no mention of it.

I will definitely keep all of this bookmarked to look at for the near future. (probably next chapter!)

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion. Loops are used for repetitive tasks, like the one you want to do. If the same thing is repeated more than 2 times, then you should probably use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is the statement where you calculate the square and cube. At that instant, the number who’s square/cube value you wish to calculate hasn’t been initialised.

For now you could multiply directly in the Sys.Outs to compute the squares and cubes individually. Once you gather what loops and recursions are, the lines of code will be significantly reduced.